Equivalence between Raw covariance and Covariance of mean over multiple MCMC chains of mean of each chain
I would like to know if the following demonstration is correct to get the equivalence, under some assumptions, between raw covariances and mean covariances over multiple chains of mean for each chain.
Important
I am using in the second method a lot of chains (1000) to be able to use Central Limit Theorem (CLT) and justify the gaussianity for posteriors with this second method.
1. Definitions
Raw Covariance:
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Cov}(x_i, x_j) = \mathbb{E}\left[\left(x_i - \mu_i\right)\left(x_j - \mu_j\right)\right],
\label{eq:raw_covariance}
\end{equation}
where $(\mu_i = \mathbb{E}[x_i]$ and $\mu_j = \mathbb{E}[x_j]$. This covariance quantifies the relationship between the parameters $x_i$ and $x_j$ at the sample level.
2. Mean of a Single Chain for Parameter $i$:
For a single chain with (M) samples:
\begin{equation}
\bar{x}_i = \frac{1}{M} \sum_{m=1}^M x_i^{(m)}.
\label{eq:mean_single_chain}
\end{equation}
3.Global Mean Across (N) Chains:
For (N) independent chains:
\begin{equation}
\bar{x}_i = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^N \bar{x}_{k,i},
\label{eq:global_mean}
\end{equation}
where:
\begin{equation}
\bar{x}_{k,i} = \frac{1}{M} \sum_{m=1}^M x_{k,i}^{(m)}.
\label{eq:mean_chain_k}
\end{equation}
4.Mean Covariance Across Chains:
The covariance of the chain means for parameters (i) and (j) is given by:
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Cov}(\bar{x}_i, \bar{x}_j) = \frac{1}{N - 1} \sum_{k=1}^N \left(\bar{x}_{k,i} - \bar{x}_i\right)\left(\bar{x}_{k,j} - \bar{x}_j\right).
\label{eq:mean_covariance}
\end{equation}
Relationship Between $\operatorname{Cov}(x_i, x_j)$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(\bar{x}_i, \bar{x}_j)$
In the general case, the covariance of the means can be expressed as:
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Cov}(\bar{x}_i, \bar{x}_j) = \frac{1}{M \cdot N} \sum_{k=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^M \sum_{k'=1}^N \sum_{m'=1}^M \operatorname{Cov}\left(x_i^{(k,m)}, x_j^{(k',m')}\right).
\label{eq:general_case}
\end{equation}
Simplification Under Homogeneity :
If we assume that the raw covariance $\operatorname{Cov}\left(x_i^{(k,m)}, x_j^{(k',m')}\right)$ is homogeneous across all samples and chains, i.e., independent of $k, m, k', m'$, and proportional to a delta term $\delta_{kk'} \cdot \delta_{mm'}$, the quadruple summation simplifies to:
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Cov}\left(x_i^{(k,m)}, x_j^{(k',m')}\right) = \delta_{kk'} \cdot \delta_{mm'} \cdot \operatorname{Cov}(x_i, x_j).
\label{eq:homogeneity_assumption}
\end{equation}
Substituting this into the quadruple summation gives:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^M \sum_{k'=1}^N \sum_{m'=1}^M \operatorname{Cov}\left(x_i^{(k,m)}, x_j^{(k',m')}\right) = 
\sum_{k=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^M \operatorname{Cov}(x_i, x_j).
\label{eq:reduction_summation}
\end{equation}
Since there are $M \cdot N$ unique terms in the summation (corresponding to every unique combination of $k$ and $m$), this simplifies further to:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^M \operatorname{Cov}\left(x_i, x_j\right) = M \cdot N \cdot \operatorname{Cov}(x_i, x_j).
\label{eq:simplification_unique_terms}
\end{equation}
Finally, substituting this back into the definition of $\operatorname{Cov}(\bar{x}_i, \bar{x}_j)$, we find:
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Cov}(\bar{x}_i, \bar{x}_j) = \frac{1}{M \cdot N} \cdot M \cdot N \cdot \operatorname{Cov}(x_i, x_j) = \operatorname{Cov}(x_i, x_j).
\label{eq:final_simplification}
\end{equation}
Thus, under the assumption of homogeneity, the mean covariance equals the raw covariance:
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Cov}(\bar{x}_i, \bar{x}_j) = \operatorname{Cov}(x_i, x_j).
\label{eq:final_equality}
\end{equation}
Reconstruction of $\operatorname{Cov}\left(x_i, x_j\right)$
Without assuming homogeneity, the relationship remains:
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Cov}\left(\bar{x}_i, \bar{x}_j\right) = \frac{1}{M \cdot N} \sum_{k=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^M \sum_{k'=1}^N \sum_{m'=1}^M \operatorname{Cov}\left(x_i^{(k,m)}, x_j^{(k',m')}\right).
\label{eq:general_reconstruction}
\end{equation}
If homogeneity is assumed, the double summation simplifies as discussed, leading to:
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Cov}(\bar{x}_i, \bar{x}_j) = \frac{1}{M \cdot N} \cdot M \cdot N \cdot \operatorname{Cov}(x_i, x_j).
\label{eq:simplification_reconstruction}
\end{equation}
This results in:
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Cov}\left(\bar{x}_i, \bar{x}_j\right) = \operatorname{Cov}(x_i, x_j).
\label{eq:final_reconstruction}
\end{equation}
Discussion and Assumptions
Key Assumptions for the Derivation

"Homogeneity of Raw Covariance:"
If $\operatorname{Cov}(x_i, x_j)$ is assumed homogeneous, the mean covariance directly equals the raw covariance.

"Independence of Samples:"
Independence ensures that the mean covariance reflects the true underlying covariance, with no spurious correlations between chains or samples.


Practical Implications

"Finite Chains:"
In real analyses, (M) and (N) are finite, introducing statistical uncertainty. As (M) and (N) increase, the estimated covariance converges to the true value.

"Special Cases:"

For well-mixed chains, homogeneity and independence assumptions often hold, making the reconstruction straightforward.
For poorly mixed chains, violations of independence or homogeneity require advanced statistical corrections.



Conclusion
The relationship between the raw covariance and the mean covariance can be summarized as follows:
In the general case:
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Cov}(\bar{x}_i, \bar{x}_j) = \frac{1}{M \cdot N} \sum_{k=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^M \sum_{k'=1}^N \sum_{m'=1}^M \operatorname{Cov}(x_i^{(k,m)}, x_j^{(k',m')}).
\label{eq:conclusion_general}
\end{equation}
Under the assumption of homogeneity:
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Cov}(\bar{x}_i, \bar{x}_j) = \operatorname{Cov}(x_i, x_j).
\label{eq:conclusion_homogeneous}
\end{equation}
These relationships emphasize the importance of validating assumptions such as homogeneity and independence when reconstructing raw covariance from mean covariance. Failure to account for these assumptions can lead to significant inaccuracies in parameter estimation, particularly in cosmological analyses involving poorly mixed chains or complex parameter spaces.
For example, with raw covariance, I get the following uggly triplot :

whereas I get the following triplot with mean of mean as explained above (with 1000 chains MCMC) :

With this method, I get pretty contours with a lot of correlations/anti-correlations.
But are the assumptions of independance between chains (that is true I think) and the homogeneity (it is harder to justify for me for the moment) valid ?
